# c++: template container, operator[] not working as expected

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a template class that wraps around a
STL container of pointers, as in:

```
tContainer_t<T, vector<T*> >
```

or

```
tContainer_t<T, list<T*> >
```

Here's the class declaration:

```
template <typename T, typename Container>
class tContainer_t
{
public:
    tContainer_t() {} //Default CTOR
    ~tContainer_t() {} //DTOR
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    size_t Size() const;
    bool Insert(T* _element);
    T* Find(T _value);
    T* Remove(T _value);
    T* operator[](size_t _index);
private:
    tContainer_t(const tContainer_t& _other); //Disable Copy
    Container m_container;
};
```

I want to practice different implementations for operator[] (for vector and list),so I wrote:

```
template <typename T, typename Container>
T* tContainer_t<T, Container>::operator[](size_t _index)
{
    T* retval;
    if (_index > m_container.size())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (typeid(m_container) == typeid(vector<T*>))
    {
        retval = m_container[_index];
    }
    if (typeid(m_container) == typeid(list<T*>))
    {
        typename Container::iterator contIter = m_container.begin();
        advance(contIter, _index);
        retval = *contIter;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

and I get strange behavior. when I use a vector in main, the code works fine. When I use a list, it doesn't even compile, showing:

```
container.h: In instantiation of ‘T* tContainer_t<T, Container>::operator[](size_t) [with T = int; Container = std::list<int*>; size_t = long unsigned int]’:
container.cpp:10:14:   required from here
container.h:141:23: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::list<int*>’ and ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’)
   retval = m_container[_index];
```

Here's how I'm using it:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    tContainer_t<int, list<int*> > a;
    int i = 5;
    a.Insert(&i);
    cout << *a[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better use specialization instead of RTTI

Comment: I'm aware of the alternatives, however it really bothers me that such a simple type checking doesn't work.

Comment: `std::list` doesn't have an `operator[]`, so there's nothing "strange" about the compiler error.

Comment: I know it doesn't have, shouldn't the typeid check avoid calling a non-existent operator and use my implementation instead?

Comment: No, because all of the code in the function gets compiled.

Comment: @susdu How is the compiler to know what the runtime evaluation `typeid(m_container) == typeid(vector<T*>)` results in when checking the syntax?

Comment: how can I solve this using RTTI?

Comment: `Container::iterator it = m_container.begin() + _index; return *it;` should do the trick. And you do not even have to check the type of your collection...

Comment: @susdu You could just use the list-implementation for every container, it will probably be optimized to the right thing. (Yes I know, does not use RTTI for fun.)

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg That won't work for `std::list`, its iterators are not  RandomAccessIterators. (At least they need not be, and on all implementations I know really aren't.)

Comment: what would I do in a case there isn't a one-size-fits-all implementation? how do you distinguish in compile-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All** the code in a function will get compiled, regardless of whether or not it'll ever get run. So this:

```
if (typeid(m_container) == typeid(vector<T*>))
{
    retval = m_container[_index];
}
```

cannot possibly ever work for `list<T>`, since `list` has no `operator[]`. Hence the compiler error. It doesn't matter that it won't get *run*, it still has to compile. The way to do this instead is to dispatch to different functions based on the type of `m_container`:

```
template <typename T, typename Container>
T* tContainer_t<T, Container>::operator[](size_t _index)
{
    if (_index > m_container.size())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return _get_index(m_container, _index);
}
```

With a `vector` version:

```
template <class T>
T* tContainer_t<T, Container>::_get_index(std::vector<T*>& v, size_t _index) {
    return v[_index];
}
```

And a `list` version:

```
template <class T>
T* tContainer_t<T, Container>::_get_index(std::list<T*>& lst, size_t _index) 
{
    typename Container::iterator contIter = lst.begin();
    advance(contIter, _index);
    return *contIter;
}
```

---

At least that's a good general approach. In this case, we don't actually have to split them up, since we can use `advance()` for both container types. It'll be cheap for the `vector` and expensive for `list`:

```
template <typename T, typename Container>
T* tContainer_t<T, Container>::operator[](size_t _index)
{
    if (_index >= m_container.size())  // note the off-by-one error I fixed here
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    auto it = m_container.begin();
    std::advance(it, _index);
    return *it;
}
```

Or simply:

```
return *std::next(m_container.begin(), _index);
```

Comment: thanks! In the case of a template class that deals with 90% identical instances and 10% completely different ones that require special care, splitting to functions is the general approach?

Comment: @susdu Yep. That's the simplest. Or just get 100% identical usages.